# Security Pattern doesn't work on first attempt

Tags: pattern-lock

On my HTC One, when I enter the correct security pattern, it doesn't always unlock the phone. No error message will be presented either. Basically nothing happens once the correct pattern has been put in.

I then need to re-enter the pattern a 2nd time, and it will then unlock the phone.

Why is this happening? Is this a known issue?

Comment: just curious what about the pin or passcode lock

Comment: @user3275057 No issues with pin/passcode lock

Comment: did u try changing the pattern??

Comment: Do you have "visible pattern" turned on? It might show you what is going on.

Comment: @user3275057 Yes I have, same issue.

Comment: @DanHulme Yes I do, I'm entering the correct pattern.

Comment: Can you just try giving it 3 seconds after the screen comes on? I think it is a lag issue